# Как искать по JSON в MariaDB?

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

У меня в базе банных (MariaDB) есть таблица с записями, у каждой записи есть поле с тегами. Теги записаны в виде массива JSON. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
id | tags
---+-------
1  | ["first", "second", "third"]
2  | ["first", "target", "second", "third"]
3  | ["foo", "bar"]
```

Так вот, мне нужно выбрать все записи, у которых, к примеру, в поле "tags" будут теги "target" и "first". Так, чтобы результат выглядел так:

```
id | tags
---+-------
2  | ["first", "target", "second", "third"]
```

Я пытался использовать для этих целей JSON_SEARCH, но он принимает только одну строчку, а не две и более, как это нужно мне.

Вопрос: как можно выполнить эту операцию, передавая два и более тега? JSON_SEARCH использовать не обязательно. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я лично чтобы не возиться со всем этим stuff's использую возможности фреймворков.

Comment: Насколько я понял, это можно успешно реализовать в PostgreSQL, и выглядеть это будет следующим образом: `SELECT id FROM pages WHERE tags::jsonb @> '{"tags":["target", "first"]}'::jsonb;`. Неужели нет ничего подобного для MariaDB?